# Hover on one div to display another div

Tags: jquery, hover, settimeout, mouseleave, mouseout

Cracking for a whole day now and still couldnt find a simple solution to this problem.

I have a class

```
  .displaynone{
      display:none;
    }
```

I am trying to

1. Hover on #hoversubheader1 and display #subheader1 by removing .displaynone on #subheader1.
2. Do not allow #subheader1 to disappear when I move my mouse from #hoversubheader1 into #subheader1
3. Add back that class to #subheader1 when my mouse is in neither #subheader1 nor #hoversubheader1.

Have yet to accomplish step 2 and 3.

I know you will want me to nest the elements, but I have reasons to not do so. In reality the two divs are separated by some 'space', so naturally I might need a setTimeout or other timing related functions for this but am also not sure if I am on the right track.

Would make my day if someone could help on this.

Markup

```
<div class="ui basic vertical segment" id="header">
        <div class="ui container">
            <div class="ui text menu">
                <a class="item">
                    Item
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui text menu displaynone" id="subheader">
                    <a class="right item" id="hoversubheader1">
                        subheadertitle1
                    </a>
                    <a class="item" id="hoversubheader2">
                        subheadertitle2
                    </a>
            </div><!--end of subheadermenu-->
            <div class="ui text menu displaynone" id="subheader1">
                    <a class="right item">
                        detail
                    </a>
                    <a class="item">
                        detail
                    </a>
            </div><!--end of subheadermenu-->
            <div class="ui text menu displaynone" id="subheader2">
                    <a class="right item">
                        detail
                    </a>
                    <a class="item">
                        detail
                    </a>
            </div><!--end of subheadermenu-->
        </div><!--end of container-->
    </div><!--end of segment-->
```

JS

```
    (function($) {
    "use strict"; // Start of use strict
    //header hover brings out subheader bar
    $("#header").hover(
      function () {
        $("#subheader").removeClass("displaynone");
      },
      function () {
        $("#subheader").addClass("displaynone");
      }
    );
    //hovering on each subheadertitle should display each subheader1, subheader2 etc
    $('#hoversubheader1,#subheader1').mouseenter(function(){

        $('#subheader1').removeClass("displaynone");
    }).mouseleave(function(){

        $("#subheader1").addClass("displaynone");

    });

    $('#hoversubheader2,#subheader2').mouseenter(function(){

        $('#subheader2').removeClass("displaynone");
    }).mouseleave(function(){

        $("#subheader2").addClass("displaynone");

    });
    }(jQuery)); // End of use strict
```

CSS

```
#header{
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.97;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    padding:0;
    padding-bottom:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}

#header > .ui.container > .ui.text.menu{
    margin-bottom:0;
}


#subheader,
#subheader1,
#subheader2{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

#subheader1,
#subheader2{
  height:200px;
}

#subheader > .ui.text.menu,
#subheader1 > .ui.text.menu,
#subheader2 > .ui.text.menu{
  margin:0;
}
#subheader.displaynone,
#subheader1.displaynone,
#subheader2.displaynone{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Some code would be great here. What is your HTML? Show the Javascript that gets closest to what you want, or what you think should work.

Comment: you realize that 2 cancels 3 don't you?

Comment: @madalinivascu hi thanks for your answer! what I meant was that we do not allow it to disappear when we are moving our mouse from the title to the subheader because by convention when you are no longer hovering on title, the subheader disappears

Comment: and in 3. you want to hide the subheader when you mouseout of it

Comment: @madalinivascu Yes, for example when I mouse out of both #subheader1 and #hoversubheader1, I want the #subheader1 content to disappear, so when I mouse into #hoversubheader2, I can show #subheader2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .general {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      border: solid 1px black;
    }
    .divClass {
      display: inline;
    }
    .divClassB {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script>
    var flag = false;

    function MouseOver(obj) {

      if (obj.id == "DivA" || obj.id == "DivB") {
        flag = true;
        document.getElementById('DivB').style.display = 'inline';
      }
      showhide(flag);
    }

    function MouseOut(obj) {

      if (obj.id == "DivA" || obj.id == "DivB")
        flag = false;
      setTimeout(function() {
        showhide(flag);
      }, 3000);

    }

    function showhide(flag) {
      if (flag) {

        document.getElementById('DivB').style.display = 'inline';
      } else
        document.getElementById('DivB').style.display = 'none'

    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <div class="general divClass" id="DivA" onmouseout="MouseOut(this)" onmouseover="MouseOver(this)">
    Div A
  </div>
  <div>
    This is for space
  </div>
  <div id="DivB" class="general divClassB" onmouseout="MouseOut(this)" onmouseover="MouseOver(this)">
    Div B
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The code I shared is pure java script. You can take clue from this.

Comment: Nice solution! Accepted as answer. However I am actually looking at a short three four liner solution using precise code logic. I am working with php for the dynamic subheaders so it has to be scalable with the database.